HDFS: how to touch recursively
We can use -R to list files recursively. HDFS: How do you list files recursively?
However, there is no -R option in hadoop fs -touch command.
When using the pipe hadoop fs -ls -R <path> | xargs hadoop fs -touch, it failed with error message
-touch: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI


The ls output is relative to the <path> and touch needs an absolute path. What is the use-case of updating the access time of existing files, though?
